# to check whether a file exists in remote server with a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on an application where I have to upload a file to the remote server.

I then wait for the file to process and sftp the processed file back to the original server.

I have managed to copy the file to the remote server using paramiko module.

How do I achieve the following?

- Create a criteria for checking whether the result file is generated on a loop basis, and
- Only proceed with the sftp once the file has been created in the remote folder.

Here is my code what i have tried so far

```
s = open("sea" + str(UID), 'w')
s.write(outtext)
s.close()
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("XXXX", username="XXXX", password="XXXXX")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
currentfile=pwd + "/sea" + str(UID)
print currentfile
destinationfile="/srv/sftp/smc-sftp-DEFAULT/inbox/sea" + str(UID)
sftp.put(currentfile,destinationfile)
outputfile="/srv/sftp/smc-sftp-DEFAULT/outbox/"
finalfile="/sea" + str(UID) + ".res"

while True:

    try:
        print(sftp.stat(outputfile+finalfile))
        print('file exists')
        sftp.get(outputfile+finalfile,pwd + "/sea" + str(UID) + ".res")
        break
    except IOError:
        print('copying file')
        continue

    sftp.close()
    ssh.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have added my trial so far.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is now solved.
it was a mistake in defining the outputfile with an extra "/"

changed them to below value.

outputfile="/srv/sftp/smc-sftp-DEFAULT/outbox"